Duplicate foreign keys using Hibernate
I'm working on a small Spring Boot project with Hibernate and I'm facing an issue with a duplicate foreign key constraint name. When Hibernate tries to create the tables in the database, it's generating an error due to a duplicate foreign key constraint name.
The error is occurring when Hibernate tries to create the tables Client and Professional, which have a foreign key to the RoleType table. The error is as follows:
alter table Client add constraint FKmgfrbay3mmsqliqsnn4vnqh9x foreign key (role_type_id) references RoleType (id)" via JDBC \[Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FKmgfrbay3mmsqliqsnn4vnqh9x'\]**

alter table Professional add constraint FKmgfrbay3mmsqliqsnn4vnqh9x foreign key (role_type_id) references RoleType (id)" via JDBC \[Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FKmgfrbay3mmsqliqsnn4vnqh9x'\]

Project configuration:

Spring Boot 3.3.4
Hibernate 6.5.3.Final
MySQL database

User class
package com.maisprati.api_barberpro.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq", sequenceName = "user_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_type_id", nullable = false)
    private RoleType roleType;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(this.roleType.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}

Client Class
package com.maisprati.api_barberpro.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client extends User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Token> tokens;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ServiceReview> serviceReviews;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_type_id", nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_CLIENT_ROLE_TYPE"))
    private RoleType roleType;

}

Professional Class
package com.maisprati.api_barberpro.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Professional")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Professional extends User {

    @Column(length = 45)
    private String phone;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String speciality;

    @Column(length = 18)
    private String documentNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professional", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ServiceType> serviceTypes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professional", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Token> tokens;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professional", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ServiceReview> serviceReviews;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professional", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_type_id", nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PROFESSIONAL_ROLE_TYPE"))
    private RoleType roleType;

}

Question:
How can I resolve this issue of duplicate foreign key constraint name in Hibernate? Is there a way to configure Hibernate to generate unique foreign key constraint names for each table?


You should remove the roleType field from the User class, or remove it from the Client and Professional classes. You inherited the Client and Professional classes from the User class, which has a foreign key roleType. However, the Client and Professional classes also have a foreign key roleType. You need to choose one of them: either leave this foreign key only in the parent class, but remove it from the children, or leave it in the children, but remove it from the parent.

Hibernate generate unique foreign key constraint names for each table, but in this case you made a mistake that prevented Hibernate from doing this.

You should not use User as a table name, as this word is reserved in some DBMS. Use users as the table name.

There is no point in using an abstract class together with @Entity, @MappedSuperclass exists for this purpose.


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_type_id")
    private RoleType roleType;

    public User(Long id, RoleType roleType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.roleType = roleType;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client extends User {

    public Client(Long id, RoleType roleType) {
        super(id, roleType);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "professionals")
public class Professional extends User {

    public Professional(Long id, RoleType roleType) {
        super(id, roleType);
    }
}


Thanks for the reply. I've already tried keeping it only in User, but for some reason I don't know yet, it doesn't work. I also mapped Role in both classes (Client and Professional), including specifying the name of the foreign keys, but hibernate does not obey, and creates the 2 keys with the same name.

@FabricioSilva I checked your case and everything works fine for me. I added my code to the answer.
